# drying water leak

Tags: water, leak

which allowed water to pour in down the side of a paneled wall and also went thru the top floor to the bottom floor. We  want to prevent mold  until we can get it torn down and replaced. It is aroundt *28 degrees at night but 48 during the day. I have no idea how to dry the area. Are we supposed to put it low (like at 30) or high like 55?

Comment: More important than temperature is ventilation and air movement.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. So, you had a water leak, and you want to dry it? And, I presume your temperatures are in degrees C?